# iOS App compiled for 4.1 worked as debug and AdHoc and after being released in app store crashes

Tags: ios, crash, iphone-sdk-4.1

Here's a strange one....

I have an app which runs rock solid since many years, and recently I did a little add on to it. I testes the app on several devices (iPhone 4, 3GS) and did that in debug an AdHoc installed modes. The app passed Apple's review process flawlessly. But now when people load the update from the app store, the app crashes randomly when pressing buttons. The crashlogs are no good because after symbolcating they show that the crash happend in main:12....

The app has been built for iOS 4.1 since ages, never a problem.

needless to say, that the keys which cause the crash have worked before and have nothing to do with the new functionality I put into the app :-(

Anyways here is one of the logs.
Any ideas?

```
Incident Identifier: 80CF0F54-3E90-4388-83E7-E4A4EA446C8B
CrashReporter Key:   7f13b873c8d4f4af689fcfb3bab5ffe5fb36e3e5
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         dbMeter [272]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/247B6966-9AEB-4C6F-BFAA-17CE5084E05D/dbMeter.app/dbMeter
Identifier:      dbMeter
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-06-24 00:25:24.171 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x42af9198
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34739c98 0x34737000 + 11416
1   CoreFoundation                  0x30b83cd6 0x30b82000 + 7382
2   CoreGraphics                    0x34a208ba 0x34a1f000 + 6330
3   CoreGraphics                    0x34a2090e 0x34a1f000 + 6414
4   CoreGraphics                    0x34a208e2 0x34a1f000 + 6370
5   UIKit                           0x30c9b898 0x30c82000 + 104600
6   UIKit                           0x30ce17ea 0x30c82000 + 391146
7   UIKit                           0x30d12a0e 0x30c82000 + 592398
8   UIKit                           0x30ca2e28 0x30c82000 + 134696
9   UIKit                           0x30ca288a 0x30c82000 + 133258
10  UIKit                           0x30ca2842 0x30c82000 + 133186
11  UIKit                           0x30c979fe 0x30c82000 + 88574
12  QuartzCore                      0x34653fa6 0x3463f000 + 85926
13  QuartzCore                      0x34653d24 0x3463f000 + 85284
14  QuartzCore                      0x34653776 0x3463f000 + 83830
15  QuartzCore                      0x34653178 0x3463f000 + 82296
16  QuartzCore                      0x34652e86 0x3463f000 + 81542
17  QuartzCore                      0x34647706 0x3463f000 + 34566
18  QuartzCore                      0x346471c6 0x3463f000 + 33222
19  QuartzCore                      0x34646fd0 0x3463f000 + 32720
20  QuartzCore                      0x3464004e 0x3463f000 + 4174
21  CoreFoundation                  0x30bf7a2e 0x30b82000 + 481838
22  CoreFoundation                  0x30bf945e 0x30b82000 + 488542
23  CoreFoundation                  0x30bfa754 0x30b82000 + 493396
24  CoreFoundation                  0x30b8aebc 0x30b82000 + 36540
25  CoreFoundation                  0x30b8adc4 0x30b82000 + 36292
26  GraphicsServices                0x30509418 0x30505000 + 17432
27  GraphicsServices                0x305094c4 0x30505000 + 17604
28  UIKit                           0x30cb0d62 0x30c82000 + 191842
29  UIKit                           0x30cae800 0x30c82000 + 182272
30  dbMeter                         0x00002b16 0x1000 + 6934
31  dbMeter                         0x00002ae0 0x1000 + 6880

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x358303ec 0x3581e000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x359076d8 0x358d3000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35907bbc 0x358d3000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35830fbc 0x3581e000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35501032 0x354fb000 + 24626
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3550203a 0x354fb000 + 28730
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x355015ea 0x354fb000 + 26090
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3590758a 0x358d3000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35907bbc 0x358d3000 + 215996

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x358303ec 0x3581e000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x359076d8 0x358d3000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35907bbc 0x358d3000 + 215996

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3582dc00 0x3581e000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3582d758 0x3581e000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30bf82b8 0x30b82000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30bfa562 0x30b82000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30b8aebc 0x30b82000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30b8adc4 0x30b82000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x361f327e 0x361ed000 + 25214
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3590630a 0x358d3000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35907bb4 0x358d3000 + 215988

Thread 5 name:  AQClient
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3582dc00 0x3581e000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3582d758 0x3581e000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30bf82b8 0x30b82000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30bfa562 0x30b82000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30b8aebc 0x30b82000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30b8adc4 0x30b82000 + 36292
6   AudioToolbox                    0x350cb772 0x350ca000 + 6002
7   AudioToolbox                    0x350ddea6 0x350ca000 + 81574
8   AudioToolbox                    0x350cb48a 0x350ca000 + 5258
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3590630a 0x358d3000 + 209674
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35907bb4 0x358d3000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00175960    r1: 0x30f76814      r2: 0x42af9190      r3: 0x34739c89
    r4: 0x42af9190    r5: 0x3e48f2b4      r6: 0x3e4a38b8      r7: 0x2fdfd714
    r8: 0x30f888c4    r9: 0x00304ed4     r10: 0x41e00000     r11: 0x41b00000
    ip: 0x3eee0250    sp: 0x2fdfd6fc      lr: 0x30b83cdd      pc: 0x34739c98
  cpsr: 0x20070030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0xcfff +dbMeter armv7  <c6b43e7537373f9db9374a4defa21acf> /var/mobile/Applications/247B6966-9AEB-4C6F-BFAA-17CE5084E05D/dbMeter.app/dbMeter
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x302a5000 - 0x302cefff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x302cf000 - 0x30306fff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30307000 - 0x30308fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x30354000 - 0x30364fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30365000 - 0x30365fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x303ca000 - 0x303f8fff  MIME armv7  <60de1fe0bbb134d788c09f7c34b1caa4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x303f9000 - 0x30419fff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x30463000 - 0x304f8fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x30505000 - 0x30511fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3053b000 - 0x3053efff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30626000 - 0x3065afff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30670000 - 0x30672fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x30673000 - 0x3078dfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x30792000 - 0x307a8fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30936000 - 0x3093dfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30941000 - 0x30949fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3094a000 - 0x3094afff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30987000 - 0x309c4fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30acf000 - 0x30b1dfff  CoreMotion armv7  <58c353bb7e33361f881da07c72f4cdfb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x30b82000 - 0x30c67fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30c68000 - 0x30c77fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <563a09bcdb2f32369b1e22f53f58273a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x30c82000 - 0x3100ffff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31030000 - 0x3111dfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3111e000 - 0x3111ffff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x31120000 - 0x3112afff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31130000 - 0x31139fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3113a000 - 0x3116dfff  StoreServices armv7  <d526715648f435c3aac4c42953e76d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3118a000 - 0x3118cfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3118d000 - 0x311defff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x311f8000 - 0x311fffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x31200000 - 0x31243fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f790c26852cb3cf298abe56bc9a3940b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x31244000 - 0x31249fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x31284000 - 0x3128ffff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31290000 - 0x313dcfff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x31400000 - 0x31400fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31401000 - 0x31402fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31403000 - 0x31423fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31430000 - 0x31472fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x319fd000 - 0x31a3dfff  CoreMedia armv7  <8e0570582ba535bfa74f1f00eef64376> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31a45000 - 0x31a7dfff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31a9d000 - 0x31abdfff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x31abe000 - 0x31afafff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x31b25000 - 0x33573fff  TextInput armv7  <f242acc046073c1598195dd26fd8ad6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x336c0000 - 0x336c5fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x336c6000 - 0x336cffff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33714000 - 0x3373dfff  ContentIndex armv7  <ecd71782cd833360872b943ecc65d203> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x337d9000 - 0x337dcfff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x337dd000 - 0x33823fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33824000 - 0x33830fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33899000 - 0x338a9fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <6956561235333e74b8ff316cb2edc93e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x33905000 - 0x33907fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33908000 - 0x3390dfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x339f9000 - 0x339fdfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33a00000 - 0x33a09fff  ITSync armv7  <ba8b48d061903e4096774344448776d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x33a9c000 - 0x33af5fff  EventKit armv7  <0d4e597ee229337183e96e921a72e30a> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x33b33000 - 0x33b37fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33b39000 - 0x33beafff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33beb000 - 0x33bf8fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x33cd1000 - 0x33cd7fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x33cd8000 - 0x33de0fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x33e39000 - 0x33e6cfff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x33fb2000 - 0x33fb3fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x33fc5000 - 0x3400cfff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x3401d000 - 0x3401ffff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x34020000 - 0x34023fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x34024000 - 0x34039fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3423e000 - 0x3423ffff  TextInput_de armv7  <df6cfcb8d32839a7b3b36ce5b0fda8de> /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_de.bundle/TextInput_de
0x34240000 - 0x34243fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x34244000 - 0x34292fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x34344000 - 0x343a3fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x34429000 - 0x3442cfff  ActorKit armv7  <f7aa6cdd654231988aafcf448978f450> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x34453000 - 0x34572fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3463f000 - 0x346eefff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x346ef000 - 0x34735fff  CoreLocation armv7  <c1924042951e3df98515c7bf36093c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x34737000 - 0x347fbfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x349e1000 - 0x34a14fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34a15000 - 0x34a1cfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34a1d000 - 0x34a1efff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x34a1f000 - 0x34b40fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x34b81000 - 0x34e6efff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34e9a000 - 0x34ecffff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34ed0000 - 0x34f8ffff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x34f90000 - 0x34fa9fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x350ca000 - 0x3521efff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x352ab000 - 0x352adfff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x352bf000 - 0x352c0fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x352c5000 - 0x3536efff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x35399000 - 0x3539efff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3548c000 - 0x354a9fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x354e3000 - 0x354f5fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x354f6000 - 0x354fafff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x354fb000 - 0x35508fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x35539000 - 0x35578fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x35579000 - 0x35579fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3557a000 - 0x35617fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35618000 - 0x35687fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35688000 - 0x356ddfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x356eb000 - 0x35817fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x3581a000 - 0x3581dfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3581e000 - 0x35835fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35884000 - 0x358cefff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x358cf000 - 0x358d1fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x358d3000 - 0x35954fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x35955000 - 0x3598dfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35990000 - 0x35a36fff  Celestial armv7  <7fbd02fa664b33babaf0327c320d1491> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x35db9000 - 0x35ebdfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x35ebe000 - 0x35ed1fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x35f1b000 - 0x35f3afff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x35f66000 - 0x35f94fff  DataAccess armv7  <3a2e67aa1d8834b7a8fc2fbb56654b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x35fd9000 - 0x3600cfff  iCalendar armv7  <34ce1957082f3518b5740ac33cfc92eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x36162000 - 0x361ecfff  Message armv7  <2cce1aa95a493906bb0227197f9e4b96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x361ed000 - 0x367f8fff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x367f9000 - 0x367fffff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3680b000 - 0x3681afff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x368cd000 - 0x368fcfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36906000 - 0x36914fff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x36927000 - 0x3692cfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36a2f000 - 0x36a2ffff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
```

Comment: What changes did you make to it?

Comment: This is why you keep the .dSYM file so you can actually READ the log files.

Comment: That is the weird thing.... I changed a recording function for dBValues from using NSMutableArray to write into a file instead. But the method which contains the new code does not even get called then the app crashes. Then I suspected some code in the didReceiveMemoryWarning method and took the code out because it was freeing that NSMutableArray which I don't need anymore. However that did not do the trick either. App crashes reliably when run without debug and never crashes when debugging

Comment: I have the .dSYM file, but that is of no help when there is a Crash in the main loop because all it tells me that the crash happened at main.m:12

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main. That sounds like you're over-releasing an object somewhere, and when it goes back to the main run loop and the default `NSAutoreleasePool` drains, it's accessing an already-released object to autorelease it.

An okay way to go about debugging this is to wrap your suspect functions with:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// the rest of the function
[pool release]; // drains the pool automatically
return; // you need to add the above line before each time you would return
```

Then hopefully you will see the function which over-releases the object. If it's a custom object being released that is causing the crash, it could be that you `autorelease` a member variable of that object which you didn't `retain` or `alloc` yourself. This is also possibly the case for any `@property (assign)`'s you use, if you ever `release` them without also having `retain`ed them.

Comment: I have tried above and I have set NSZombieEnabled to YES. The silly thing is that when running with debugger the app does not crash. As soon as I start it without debugger it crashes reliably, but then I just get the useless stack trace. So back to the drawing board :-(

Answer (score 0):

wowzers.... I finally found the issue and i can't wait to share.

**"Guard Malloc" and "Enable Guard Edges"** finally helped me finding the bug. Two Float32 arrays were allocated using calloc, but the index accessing them and writing the Float32s into it was too big by 1 (haven't we heard that before?!?).

After enabling Guard Malloc the debugger stopped right at the source code point where the wrong access has happened, but it wasn't too obvious why. Being bored with calloc (in fact always have been since my early C coding days) I changed the arrays to be NSMUtableArrays and guess what, Guard Malloc again stopped at the same line of code (this time with the NSMutableArray replacing the *Float32 pointers), but because it is Objective-C it also told me that the Index was out of bounds and gave me a stack trace.

The fix of course then was easy by allocating the right sizes for the arrays, however what worries me is that this wrong code was in the App since 2008 and it never caused any problems! Just now that I added something to the App memory must have been shifted to the "dark side".

**So.... there you have it, when you get a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in your main, watch out for calloc / malloc / free and check, double check and recheck your indices.**

By the way, in Xcode 4 setting those flags for Guard Malloc, etc. is done through "Edit Scheme"